# iOS - Secure way to get data out of an app for a researcher

Tags: ios, xcode

tl;dr What's the "right" way to get my data off an iPad such that only a researcher can receive and read it?

Full Explanation:
In my app, I've got to get the data from a database off the app and to a researcher. This will consist (most likely) of two separate files. The first will be table of identifying information:
ID  FirstName ... etc.

This is sensitive identifying information that has to be sent so that only the researcher can get it.

The other will be de-identified info that uses ID numbers and the like, and it doesn't necessarily have to be secure, but I would like to only have it go to the researcher, obviously.

So far, I've only ever worked with data that can just be emailed, but there are some problems with this implementation. You can't just up and send an email; you can only present an email composition view ready to send, and then the user can edit the email before sending it. So a user could send this data to someone else.

Another wrench in the works: this researcher doesn't have access to a server, so I can't do SFTP uploads that way. It's also not guaranteed that the app will have internet access all the time.

The best idea I've got so far is to have a button to compose an email that attaches an encrypted file, protected by a password whose hash is hard-coded, I mean, compile-time provisioned, into the app.

EDIT: Here's what I'm going to do for the time being: use some personal server space so I can implement SFTP uploading, and then I will work with the researcher to get some server space they can use. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What about using something like Flurry

Comment: Isn't Flurry data analytics? Can you elaborate on how I would use that to get user data out?

Comment: I thought you could send an arbitrary file, but on second thoughts I think that might be testfight as opposed to flurry. The file could of course be encrypted if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is not particularly "safe" but if you just want to send email to one specific address, without the possibility of user intervening, you can use SMTP protocol yourself.

In one of my old apps I used [skpsmtpmessage](https://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) - I don't know if it still works, but if not there should be more solutions like it.

What it does is basically send email messages programatically, without using the composer dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there any way I can secure the email contents, e.g. by encrypting the file attachment like I suggested above? Or is that inadequate?

Comment: There is no general **adequate** or **inadequate** in security - it all depends on what you are sending. I have no idea what you are sending, but for starters, I'd compress and password protect the data - it would be smaller so faster upload, and if someone would intercept it, she would have to at least put some effort in.